# selecting object in an array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to make it possible so that by clicking on a 'client' in one of the following `<td>`s I can select that specific object from the 'clients' array and switch to a new view. I assume I would want to start with an ng-click, just not sure how to go about it. Also I will not be using any jquery.

```
<div ng-init="clients = [
    {firstname:'Buster', lastname:'Bluth', tagid:'4134'},
    {firstname:'John', lastname:'McClane', tagid:'9845'},
    {firstname:'Mister', lastname:'Spock', tagid:'0905'}
    ]"></div>
<div>
    <div>Clients</div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                     <th>First Name</th>
                     <th>Last Name</th>
                     <th>I-Number</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat="client in clients">
                       <td>{{client.firstname}}</td>
                       <td>{{client.lastname}}</td>
                       <td>{{client.inumber}}</td>
                   </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-click` is the correct approach. You can get the selected object like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients" ng-click="redirect(client)">
```

Create a controller with the method:

```
function ctrl($scope, $location){
    $scope.redirect = function(client){
        console.log(client);
        $location.url('/someurl'); //this is the routing defined in the $routingProvider, you need to implement it.
    }
}
```

Make sure you refer to the class in the outer div containing the select like this

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl'>
```